# How to create symbolic matrix dynamically in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-math

I need to create a symbolic matrix in MATLAB. It can be done statically as

```
syms a11 a12 a21 a22;
A = [a11 a12; a21 a22];
```

or using compact syntax as

```
A = sym('A%d', [2 2]);
```

However i don't see how any of these syntax's should allow dynamic initialization. I would like to initialize each matrix element individually using two loops. One shot at a possible syntax (it's NOT valid MATLAB syntax) could be

```
syms a x1;
P = sym(zeros(n,n));
for l = 1:n
   for m = 1:n
      kl = l; km = m;
      P(l,m)(x1) = a*sin(kl*x1)*sin(km*x1);
   end
end
```

where I used the (invalid) syntax P(l,m)(x1) to specify that each element in P is a function of x1. Hence P(2) would be an (n,n) matrix with elements P(l,m) = a*sin(kl*2)*sin(km*2). I know it's possible to construct the P by building the matrix string (A=[...]) on run time and evaluating using **eval**. Something like

```
syms a x1;
command = [];
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        kl = i; km = j;
        command = [command ' + a*sin(' num2str(kl) '*x1)*sin(' num2str(km) '*x1)'];
        if(j < n) command = [command ',']; end
    end
    if(i < n) command = [command ';']; end
end
eval(['P(x1) = [' command '];'])
```

However, using **eval** is bad practice, so I see this solution only as a last resort. Is there any *correct* way to achieve my goal?

NB: I have written the elements P(l,m) = a*sin(kl*x1)*sin(km*x1) to simplify the code. The actual expression is P(l,m) = sin(kl*x1)*sin(km*x1)*epsilon + kl*km*cos(kl*x1)*cos(km*x1).*b + km*cos(km*x1)*sin(kl*x1)-kl*cos(kl*x1)*sin(km*x1)/(kl^2-km^2).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What about just initializing the matrix as you indicate, and then looping afterwards? -- Consider adding a small example of the input and output that you expect.

Comment: The problem is that i cannot specify the index (l,m) and the dependence (x1) simultaneously; P(l,m)(x1) = ... is invalid syntax. If I simply write P(l,m) = ..., P will not be a function of x1. If I write P(x1) = ..., P will not be a matrix but rater a 1 x 1 symbolic expression.

Comment: If you know a way to get the result that you want (for example via eval, or by doing it manually) please do so and edit the result into your post stating how you got to it. Pure descriptions are pretty hard to go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to avoid the `for` loops, you can use [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html), which hides them from you:

```
syms a x1
n = 3;
x = meshgrid(1:n)*x1; % multiplying by the symbolic x1 makes x symbolic
P = a*sin(x).*sin(x.');
```

which returns

```
P =

[         a*sin(x1)^2,   a*sin(2*x1)*sin(x1),   a*sin(3*x1)*sin(x1)]
[ a*sin(2*x1)*sin(x1),         a*sin(2*x1)^2, a*sin(2*x1)*sin(3*x1)]
[ a*sin(3*x1)*sin(x1), a*sin(2*x1)*sin(3*x1),         a*sin(3*x1)^2]
```